# System call poll() does not work on Ubuntu Kylin 16.04 32 bit version, but works on Fedora 21 64 bit

Tags: c, polling, ubuntu-16.04

This is a short version of my code: I have a 64 bit fedora 21 on which the code works fine. However on my other 32bit machine on which I have installed ubuntu  Kylin 16.04 32 bit version, poll does not return when text is entered on stdin, it just stays blocked. When I hit Ctrl-C in gdb after the text is entered, and then try executing next command it works... Is this a bug of ubuntu 32 bit version or I have to use poll differently on 32 bit version?

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/poll.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int           sockfd;
  int const  myOPEN_MAX=100,MAXLINE=4096;
  struct pollfd   client[myOPEN_MAX];
  int maxi,nready,n;
  char buf[4096];
  client[0].fd = fileno(stdin);
  client[0].events = POLLRDNORM;
  for (int i = 1; i < myOPEN_MAX; i++){
    client[i].fd = -1;      /* -1 indicates available entry */
  }
  maxi = 1;                 /* max index into client[] array */
  printf("enter something\n");
  for ( ; ; ) {
    nready = poll(client, maxi+1, -1);
    for (int i = 0; i <= maxi; i++) {   /* check all clients for data */
      if ( (sockfd = client[i].fd) < 0)
    continue;
      if (client[i].revents & (POLLRDNORM | POLLERR)) {
        if ( (n = read(sockfd, buf, MAXLINE)) > 0) {
          if (i == 0) { //stdin
            printf("works\n");
           return 0;
          }
          if (--nready <= 0)
           break;               /* no more readable descriptors */
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: I suggest using the macro `STDIN_FILENO`, or even a literal `0`, instead of `fileno(stdin)`.

Comment: I suggest `POLLIN` instead of `POLLRDNORM`.  They mean the same thing, but the latter has feature dependencies.

Comment: You are specifying `maxi+1` (== 2) fds when calling `poll()`, but only the first `struct pollfd` contains a valid file descriptor.

Comment: Other than the `nfds` thing, I don't see anything wrong with your code, and it works for me on 64-bit CentOS 6.  I don't see any reason to think that it would fail on Ubuntu 16.04 (when built there), architecture notwithstanding.

Comment: Perhaps, though, you're running into a buffering issue.  The terminal in which you are testing the program may buffer what you type differently or not at all in one distro vs. the other.  Redirecting the standard input from a file should sidestep any such issues.

Comment: Linux / glibc `poll()` has worked fine on Linux since well before 64-bit systems were common.  It is highly doubtful that your problem is there.

Comment: There may be a Kylin-specific bug, or something about your Kylin installation may be broken, but I'm not prepared to believe that the behavioral difference you observe is directly related to machine architecture.

Comment: You are not initializing everything in your `struct pollfd` array, so you are passing garbage into `poll()` . 1. Check the return value of   ALL your system calls for errors, you want to know if any of them fails. 2. Run your program under the `strace` tool, it might give you quick insight into what's going on. 3. Describe in detail how you are testing your program, so others can replicate it.

Comment: changing maxi+1 to maxi makes no difference

Comment: Using POLLIN instead of POLLRDNORM solved the problem. How do I credit  John Bollinger for it?